# Passing vertex attributes with layouts in geometry shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, geometry-shader, vertex-attributes

Let's say we have a GL program consisting of the following vertex, geometry and fragment shaders.

vertex:

```
#version 410
layout (location = 0) in vec2 pos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 size;
layout (location = 2) in float rot;
layout (location = 3) in vec4 color;

layout (location = 0) out vec2 p;
layout (location = 1) out vec2 s;
layout (location = 2) out float r;
layout (location = 3) out vec4 c;

void main(){
    gl_Position = vec4(pos,0.0,1.0);

    p = pos;
    s = size;
    r = rot;
    c = color;
}
```

geometry:

```
#version 410
layout (points) in;
layout (triangle_strip, max_vertices = 4) out;

layout (location = 0) in vec2 pos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 size;
layout (location = 2) in float rot;
layout (location = 3) in vec4 color;

layout (location = 0) out vec2 p;
layout (location = 1) out vec2 s;
layout (location = 2) out float r;
layout (location = 3) out vec4 c;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = gl_in[0].gl_Position + vec4(-0.2, -0.2, 0.0, 0.0);    // 1:bottom-left
    EmitVertex();
    gl_Position = gl_in[0].gl_Position + vec4( 0.2, -0.2, 0.0, 0.0);    // 2:bottom-right
    EmitVertex();
    gl_Position = gl_in[0].gl_Position + vec4(-0.2,  0.2, 0.0, 0.0);    // 3:top-left
    EmitVertex();
    gl_Position = gl_in[0].gl_Position + vec4( 0.2,  0.2, 0.0, 0.0);    // 4:top-right
    EmitVertex();
    EndPrimitive();

    p = pos;
    s = size;
    r = rot;
    c = color;
}
```

fragment:

```
#version 410

layout (location = 0) in vec2 pos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 size;
layout (location = 2) in float rot;
layout (location = 3) in vec4 color;

out vec4 FragColor;

void main()
{
    FragColor = color;
}
```

The program takes points and display them as quads.

What I'm trying to do here is to pass the 4 vertex attributes (pos, size, rot and color) to the fragment shader through the geometry shader.

If I remove the geometry shader from my program, it manages to pass the vertex attributes to the fragment shaders and it displays colored dots.

If I keep the geometry shader and remove the layouts (in and out), it displays black quads.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: you seem to be setting the attributes only at the end after all the vertices have already been emitted?

Comment: Yes, that was the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues in your code. I've renamed all of the variables so you can see what's going on (This probably wouldn't be a massive problem, since you are using layout qualifiers, but I'll stick with a naming that makes it obvious what's happening).

```cpp
#version 410

// per-vertex attributes from the vertex buffers
layout (location = 0) in vec2 vs_pos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 vs_size;
layout (location = 2) in float vs_rot;
layout (location = 3) in vec4 vs_color;

// per-vertex inputs to the geometry shader
layout (location = 0) out vec2 gs_pos;
layout (location = 1) out vec2 gs_size;
layout (location = 2) out float gs_rot;
layout (location = 3) out vec4 gs_color;

void main(){
    gl_Position = vec4(vs_pos,0.0,1.0);

    // pass vars from vertex shader, to geometry shader
    gs_pos = vs_pos;
    gs_size = vs_size;
    gs_rot = vs_rot;
    gs_color = vs_color;
}
```

```cpp
#version 410
layout (points) in;
layout (triangle_strip, max_vertices = 4) out;

// when passed to the geometry shader, these variables are now arrays!
// be sure to declare them as such...
layout (location = 0) in vec2 gs_pos[];
layout (location = 1) in vec2 gs_size[];
layout (location = 2) in float gs_rot[];
layout (location = 3) in vec4 gs_color[];

// the outputs to the fragment shader are presented as
// single attributes though 
layout (location = 0) out vec2 fs_pos;
layout (location = 1) out vec2 fs_size;
layout (location = 2) out float fs_rot;
layout (location = 3) out vec4 fs_color;
void main()
{
    // pass vars for 1st vertex generated
    // (you may be able to get away with setting these once prior
    // to the first EmitVertex call, not sure, it's been a while!)
    fs_pos = gs_pos[0];
    fs_size = gs_size[0];
    fs_rot = gs_rot[0];
    fs_color = gs_color[0];    
    gl_Position = gl_in[0].gl_Position + vec4(-0.2, -0.2, 0.0, 0.0);
    EmitVertex(); //< emits all params above!

    // pass vars for 2nd vertex generated, etc... 
    fs_pos = gs_pos[0];
    fs_size = gs_size[0];
    fs_rot = gs_rot[0];
    fs_color = gs_color[0];    
    gl_Position = gl_in[0].gl_Position + vec4( 0.2, -0.2, 0.0, 0.0);
    EmitVertex(); //< emits all params above!

    fs_pos = gs_pos[0];
    fs_size = gs_size[0];
    fs_rot = gs_rot[0];
    fs_color = gs_color[0];    
    gl_Position = gl_in[0].gl_Position + vec4(-0.2,  0.2, 0.0, 0.0);
    EmitVertex(); //< emits all params above!

    fs_pos = gs_pos[0];
    fs_size = gs_size[0];
    fs_rot = gs_rot[0];
    fs_color = gs_color[0];    
    gl_Position = gl_in[0].gl_Position + vec4( 0.2,  0.2, 0.0, 0.0);
    EmitVertex(); //< emits all params above!

    EndPrimitive();

}
```

And finally the geometry shader.

```cpp
#version 410

// the inputs to the fragment shader would have been interpolated
// across the geometry primitive emitted by the GS. 
layout (location = 0) in vec2 fs_pos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 fs_size;
layout (location = 2) in float fs_rot;
layout (location = 3) in vec4 fs_color;

out vec4 FragColor;

void main()
{
    FragColor = fs_color;
}
```